# Showing $(1-x^2)u''-xu'+9u=x^3$ is formally self-adjoint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, self-adjoint-operators

> I want to show $$(1-x^2)u''-xu'+9u=x^3 \ \ \ \ \ \ -1\leq x\leq 1$$
>   can be written in formally self-adjoint form.

My attempt:

Calculate the integrating factor,
$$\exp\left(-\int \frac{x \ dx}{1-x^2}\right)\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{\exp(\ln(\sqrt{1-x^2}))}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
Then, 
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-x^2}u''-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}u'+\frac{9}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}u&=\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
\left(\sqrt{1-x^2} u'\right)'+\frac{9}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}u&=\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} 
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)\\ 
-\left(\sqrt{1-x^2} u'\right)'+\left(-\frac{9}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}u\right)&=-\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} 
\end{align}
Hence this is in the form $Lu=-(pu')'+qu$, where,
$$p=\sqrt{1-x^2}, q=-\frac{9}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
Is this correct? I am not sure if I am allowed to express $q$ the way I did, as i'm *unsure if $q$ can be negative*.

[image]

Comment: You introduced the negative sign by multiplying by $-1$ in the middle step. You want to write it as $Lu=-( (pu')'+qu)$ in which case $p$ and $q$ are both positive definite on the inside of the domain.

Comment: I am a little bit confused after line $(1)$. I multiplied by $-1$ so $(pu')'$ would be negative, as I thought this was required.

Comment: In the form I'm familiar with, both terms should have the same sign (traditionally, minus in front of everything, but that's just a convention). If you check [Sturm-Lioville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory#Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_equations_as_self-adjoint_differential_operators) wiki, you will find the same.

Comment: Okay, now I'm worried haha I've included the theorem which was provided in my lecture notes. Does this help?

Comment: I see. It's just a matter of convention, I think. Anyway, it is important for positive definiteness, but for self-adjoint property, the sign is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, cool. So would my solution be correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. And verification of self-adjoint property in this form is universal (integration by parts).